# Contains(), how to reverse using lambda

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have these 4 checkboxes, which constitute the string variables saljes, kopes, bytes, erbjudes. When they are checked they get the value "on".

From this I put together a string variable (p) that contains all the numbers I want to include in the LINQ-statement.
Let say if all the checkboxes are checked, i would get a string that is "1234", and if only checkbox 2 and 4 are checked, it would result in "24".

In my database I have a field called "Type" which is of type int. I want to tell the database to include all the rows that have a "Type" value that can be found in the string p.

Something like this (of course my code doesn't work, therefore I need you guys):

```
        var searchResult = from s in db.Ads select s;
        string p = "1";

        if (saljes != "on")
            p = p.Replace("1", "");
        if (kopes == "on")
            p += "2";
        if (bytes == "on")
            p += "3";
        if (erbjudes == "on")
            p += "4";

        searchResult = searchResult.Where(s => p.Contains(s => s.Type.ToString());
```

What I kinda need to do is a reversed Contains(), but how?

Comment: You can't use `IEnumerable<String> p`? You can always `String.Join` it if you need it combined, but would allow you more control with regards to getting individual values. The other option is to use bits: `Int32 p;` and test `(p & 1)`, `(p & 4)`, etc.

Comment: So if your string is `"234"` a value of `24` should be found in your db?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me -- it would be useful to see a few examples of what you want to have happen for various "Type" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains()` already is a 'reversed IN', as described [here](http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql):

```
int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;
```

So simply fill a List:

```
var list = new List<int>();

if (saljes == "on")
    list.Add(1);
if (kopes == "on")
    list.Add(2);
if (bytes == "on")
    list.Add(3);
if (erbjudes == "on")
    list.Add(4);

var searchResult = db.Ads.Where(s => list.Contains(s.Type));
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Although I had to modify the code a bit. If I tried the lambda expression within the Contains() it said "Cannot convert lambda expression to type int because it is not a delegate type". Although if i only write searchResult = searchResult.Where(s => list.Contains(s.Type)); it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Not clear what the problem is, but this should work:

```
searchResult = searchResult.Where(s => p.Contains(s.Type.ToString());
```

`p` is string and [Contains(string value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) expects string as parameter, so you don't need lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

Would this expression do it?

```
s => s.Type.ToString().ToCharArray().Except(p.ToCharArray()).Count() == 0
```

E.g. if `s.Type` is `24` and `p` is `"234"` then `s.Type` is included in the string. If we convert the `int` to a char-array we get

```
{'2', '4'}
```

The string converted to a char-array is

```
{'2', '3', '4'}
```

It means that the digits of the `int` are all included in the `string`. So the `int` digits except the `string` digits yield an empty set that we test with `Count() == 0`.

```
{'2', '4'}.Except({'2', '3', '4'}) ==> { }
```

---

Instead of creating a `string`, I would create a `List<char>`

```
var p = new List<char>();               

if (saljes == "on") p.Add('1');               
if (kopes == "on") p.Add('2');               
if (bytes == "on") p.Add('3');               
if (erbjudes == "on") p.Add('4');
```

Then the expression becomes

```
s => s.Type.ToString().ToCharArray().Except(p).Count() == 0
```

---

However, be aware of the fact that this cannot be converted to an appropriate SQL-where clause. Therefore the whole table will have to be scanned.